# Convert vBulletin to Drupal but maintain friendly urls for SEO?

Tags: drupal, url, hyperlink, vbulletin

I'm fed up with VB and looking to convert a big vBulletin board to Drupal. But I don't want to lose the links of the friendly urls and risk having everything re-indexed by Google. How can I maintain those urls? The site and huge has been around since 2002. I don't want to be penalised by Google.

Comment: Frankly, having experience with both, I wouldn't convert from vBulletin to Drupal without a very, very good reason. Drupal's forum functionality leaves a lot to be desired. I love Drupal, but not for things vBulletin does well.

Comment: Drupal is a lot more flexible. VB has been bought up by a company who seems to be messin' it up. I don't have confidence vBulletin will remain  tops in the future. I wanna convert to Drupal but I'm scared of the hit I'd take with SEO.

Answer (score 1):

With path (part of Drupal core) and [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) you can create user friendly urls.

Path allows you to change how your urls look at a per url basis, where path_auto helps you with automatically creating those urls based on some simplerules when content is created etc.

Comment: Paths can be set by migrate and can stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am now dealing with a site that was migrated from vBulletin to Drupal 7 using native Forum (+Advanced Forum).

In the migration I inherited, they built new SEO-friendly URLs using PathAuto but did not make URL aliases [ !? ]. You at least will be using the same URLS.

**But either way you will need do something for the replies/comments.**

In vBulletin replies to threads are the same content type as the first post in a thread - all 'posts'. But in D7 the first post in a thread is a 'node' and all the replies are just 'comments' on that node.

The standard Drupal Migrate tool will make a table in your database mapping the vBulletin post to the D7 comment, but it will not make a URL alias, so any requests that come in for a specific post will get a 404 unless you handle them.

You can get the `threadid` for the post in the vBulletin db, and then look up the D7 node that the post will now belong to [as a comment] in the `migrate_map_forum_threads` or similar table in your D7 db.

I wrote a script to join the data from both DBs to create a map, you can have it if you like.

I am still figuring out the best way to actually use the map since on my virtual server I do not have permission to use mod_rewrite's RewriteMap directive. If you can use that it is the way to go; have Apache handle all the mapping before Drupal even gets involved.